# Suggestions for questions that need a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

When I started here, I would have never believed I could reach 10k but I did and am more than happy with that level of reputation.

So, I decided I would offer any excess rep I made, as a bounty on worthwhile posts.

I have found myself unsure of which questions really deserve a bounty, so I thought, why not put it to the community.

I would like people to suggest the best questions that could benefit from this. Put them in answers below and let others vote to decide which posts are the most deserving and I will give out the bounties based on voting.

**Some criteria for suggesting questions:**

- Well written
- Clear and answerable
- I would rather people did not suggest their own posts, to keep things
  fair
- I would rather have unanswered questions (but giving them to great
  existing answers is not out of the question)
- I will give 100 rep per bounty

That's about it, I hope you guys have some worthwhile post to suggest to me :)

Comment: congratulations on reaching it! I hope I can reach it too.

Comment: @MarkYisri I am sure you can :) I was a total novice question asker when I started four yeas ago, if I can do it, anyone can.

Comment: 4 years to do it !!

Comment: Well, four years of membership, like I said, I came as an asker but after I gained some knowledge, I came back and used it to answer questions. It was more like one and a bit years to go from just under 1k to 10k. 300 to 400 posts seems the average for reaching 10k but the more you answer the better you will get and the quicker it will go up.

Comment: @MarkYisri less than 4, depending on how much of a nut you are 

Comment: Mark, I think this question deserves a bounty: http://askubuntu.com/q/854602/595510

Comment: @MarkYisri Can you please put that in an answer, with a reason why it needs a bounty.

Answer (score 5):

[How to read systemd journal file on system that has no systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/617290/37165)

asked: 1 year ago, viewed: 1526 times

This is relevant for users who are still trapped between [upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upstart) and [systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/systemd) system management; systemd is becoming more common but remained controversial and unanswered.

**Bounty Awarded**

Comment: This one made 4 votes quite quick, I will put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have listed 7 questions that may need for bounty and good answers for many users. The following questions are mostly well written, likely answerable and have zero answers.

**Suggested for bounty**

1. [How to read systemd journal file on system that has no systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/617290/37165)

   asked: 1 year ago, viewed: 1526 times
2. [How to convert this custom upstart job to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/806300/37165)

   asked: 3 months ago, viewed: 252 times
3. [Howto to set AltGr key with xmodmap](https://askubuntu.com/q/497565/37165)

   asked: 2 years ago, viewed: 664 times
4. [Xubuntu - how to disable SHIFT toggles numpad keys?](https://askubuntu.com/q/270790/37165)

   asked: 3 years ago, viewed: 777 times
5. [How do I change the icon size in the KDE status bar?](https://askubuntu.com/q/420598/37165)

   asked: 2 years ago, viewed: 412 times
6. [How to use xdg-desktop-icon?](https://askubuntu.com/q/190955/37165)

   asked: 4 years ago, viewed: 383 times

   - related: cross-posted as [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12570662)
7. [How do I enable pressure for my Wacom Intuos L?](https://askubuntu.com/q/292868/37165)

   asked: 3 years ago, viewed: 261 times

**Suggested reasoning**

The following are my own reasoning with least knowledge.

- Question 1, 2 are relevant for users who are still trapped between [upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upstart) and [systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/systemd) system management; systemd is becoming more common but remained controversial and unanswered.
- Question 3, 4 are relevant for users who want to configure modifier keys on their [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard); Sounds like common problem but unanswered.
- Question 5 is relevant for users who are still struggling to use HiDPI display with certain desktop environment, in this case, [kde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kde); HiDPI users on Kubuntu might be able to answer this today.
- Question 6 is relevant for users who prefer cross-desktop solution to install something, in this case, using [xdg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xdg) tool to install new icon; Despite cross-posted, it seems to be a straightforward question but remained unanswered.
- Question 7 is relevant for users who own [wacom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wacom) drawing tablets and still stuggling to use in Ubuntu; While 'Wacom Intuos L' is being asked, there is no canonical answer that explains why pressure sensitivity for Wacom drawing tablets sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work. [This article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom) on Ubuntu Wiki has dated instructions that might need clarification.

**How I select**

At first, I use the following criteria in the search bar on Ask Ubuntu. The result was very low (4 results).

```
is:question views:250 answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no wiki:no score:10
```

So I lowered the criteria by reducing the question score filter from 10 to 5 and refine my search. Then, many questions flooded the page (133 results).

```
is:question views:250 answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no wiki:no score:5
```

From there, I browse the results briefly and proceeded to view random questions that may be relevant and somewhat familiar to many users.

Despite my suggested questions, none of those are applicable to myself. Should suggested questions above are all disqualified, then someone should refine the search and post another meta answer.

Comment: Better post separate suggestions, so we can vote for it :)

Comment: Um... I guess I will copy-paste suggested questions into other 7 meta answers as community wiki. Edit: Oh no... trivial answers are automatically converted into comments. I guess I will add more text i.e. reasonings to be a valid meta answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have posted separately as community wiki. Despite not applicable to myself, I won't be voting any of suggested questions.

Answer (score 1):

[How to convert this custom upstart job to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/806300/37165)

asked: 3 months ago, viewed: 252 times

This is relevant for users who are still trapped between [upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upstart) and [systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/systemd) system management; systemd is becoming more common but remained controversial and unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

[Howto to set AltGr key with xmodmap](https://askubuntu.com/q/497565/37165)

asked: 2 years ago, viewed: 664 times

This is relevant for users who want to configure modifier keys on their [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard); Sounds like common problem but unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

[Xubuntu - how to disable SHIFT toggles numpad keys?](https://askubuntu.com/q/270790/37165)

asked: 3 years ago, viewed: 777 times

This is relevant for users who want to configure modifier keys on their [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard); Sounds like common problem but unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I change the icon size in the KDE status bar?](https://askubuntu.com/q/420598/37165)

asked: 2 years ago, viewed: 412 times

This is relevant for users who are still struggling to use HiDPI display with certain desktop environment, in this case, [kde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kde); HiDPI users on Kubuntu might be able to answer this today.

Answer (score 0):

[How to use xdg-desktop-icon?](https://askubuntu.com/q/190955/37165)

asked: 4 years ago, viewed: 383 times, related: [cross-posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12570662)

This is relevant for users who prefer cross-desktop solution to install something, in this case, using [xdg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xdg) tool to install new icon; Despite cross-posted, it seems to be a straightforward question but remained unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I enable pressure for my Wacom Intuos L?](https://askubuntu.com/q/292868/37165)

asked: 3 years ago, viewed: 261 times

This is relevant for users who own [wacom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wacom) drawing tablets and still stuggling to use in Ubuntu; While 'Wacom Intuos L' is being asked, there is no canonical answer that explains why pressure sensitivity for Wacom drawing tablets sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work. [This article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom) on Ubuntu Wiki has dated instructions that might need clarification.