# Giving away bounties this December 2019

Tags: discussion, bounty

I hope the plain title can still catch your attention--initially worded as "presents" instead of "bounties" but I decided for latter that has a clear intention.

Back then, [this meta post (2016)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16403/37165) had asked for questions that need a bounty and I was the only user that had given suggestions at the time. Three years later today, I am writing this meta post to ask similarly from the other position.

We are now approaching the end of year 2019, so I would like to take this opportunity to offer bounties to selected questions. I could do the advanced search [like I did last time](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16409/37165), but I don't have much time left to sieve each and every questions by end of this year.

So if anyone had bookmarked some unanswered questions but was [in no mood](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+no+mood+to+do) to research and write a good answer, then this might motivate you to write one!

Suggestions are open to not just one, but few questions that need or deserve a bounty. I have listed own criteria for suggesting questions as follows.

1. Bounty from 250 onwards for **maximum six (6) selected questions**;
2. Each question **must have a supporting reason for deserving a bounty** that can be either: unanswered, or has answers but underappreciated;
3. The questions asked by **active users with points 1,000 and below**--preferably not own posts--will have the **highest priority**.

Suggestion template prepared as follows.

```
https://askubuntu.com/q/{12345}

1. Bounty suggested: {250|300|350|400|450|500}

2. Reason suggested: {must have a reason to convince}

3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? {yes|no}
```

Post separately: **one suggestion per meta answer**. Copy and paste above template and replace `{text in curly brackets}` with `text of choice`.

Open to suggestions **from now until 29 December 2019, 23:59 UTC**.

That is all, and I may review your suggestions soon.

Comment: Looking back on when I did this and at your post now, I think, even though the post are well received, it is kind of preaching to the choir. Meta is frequented by established users who have the rep and amount of content that offering a bounty is trivial and they will earn the rep back passively in just a few days. This means that if they think something deserves a bounty, they just award it and move on. I think this post would get a lot more answers if there was some way to get it to the general users, who do not use meta. unfortunately, I don't know a way to achieve that.

Comment: Another alternative to get some more interaction could be to open it up to include the highly voted but unanswered questions https://askubuntu.com/unanswered and try to encourage answers on them but this is different to what you intend in the post and could result in the rep going to waste. That is all I can think of right now but it would be a shame to see another one of these offers go to waste.

Comment: Sure, I don't expect most general users to use meta. This meta post is intended to encourage *established users* to help discover and promote good questions posted by general users with low rep. Then again, if *anyone* had bookmarked and aware of such questions, then they can also suggest that here too. May be better than doing advanced search by myself--recently I had wasted -200 points and failed to get any good answer for such questions.

Comment: @MarkKirby I understand "established users" as users with some experience using this site and *not necessarily* being the high rep users. Hence my meta post and earlier comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meta post will summarize the selection results and related findings.

**Selection results**: 5 suggested, 3 selected for bounties. All bounties were opened to reward existing answer, although some questions remain unanswered (#2, #3, #4).

1. [Dec 20](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18929): [Pros and cons of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/1009311) (*selected*)
2. [Dec 21](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18933): [Different colors for active/inactive Unity window title bars?](https://askubuntu.com/q/943147) (*selected*)
3. [Dec 25](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18934): [How to format a SD card easily in KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/213511)
4. [Dec 26](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18938): [Is it possible to run Windows 10 UWP apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991858)
5. [Dec 29](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18941): [Can a Raspberry Pi run Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/212346) (*selected*)

Question #2 should be highly concerned, as there seems to be no way to make Ubuntu more friendly to colour-blind users. The high contrast themes are "broken" and almost all themes were not designed to differentiate colours for active/inactive window title bars. Bounty, even twice, has failed to get the real answer.

**Related findings**: Through this meta post, there are few things that may be inferred alongside user experience of myself as the meta original poster.

- Meta may not be visited by established users with relatively low reputation points (around 1,500 points and below)--I similarly have started to engage meta only when reaching that range few years ago, and before that I may have visited but never engaged in meta.
- Bounty indeed draws attention, but seems hardly effective at encouraging users to post an answer that actually answer the question--bounty instead may be ignored, or tend to receive new duplicate answers that are not any better than existing answers.
- The amount of bounty may be downplayed and does not necessarily valued by users--almost all bounties that I had earned over the years worth only 50 points each, which I had engaged only because there were no other answers that satisfy the question and I was willing to invest some time and had the means to write a better answer at the time; otherwise, unanswered questions with bounty given with 50 or 100 points may be often downplayed (not just on Ask Ubuntu but other SE sites that I have engaged).
- Getting a good answer is basically finding a good match that fits the question, and bringing discussion on meta--even if that turned out "preaching to the choir" (having the wrong audience) as pointed by a commentator--was the only known way to clarify this matter.

**Credits**: Thanks to all users who engaged in this meta post.

- [@karel](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel), the first and the only suggested post besides the original poster
- [@Fabby](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/344926/fabby), the one provided bounties to 2 suggested posts
- [@MarkKirby](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby), [@user.dz](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/26246/user-dz) and other commentators
- and all annonymous voters (+18/-2)

That is all to share.

Answer (score 7):

[Pros and cons of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/1009311)

1. Bounty suggested: 250
2. Reason suggested: The accepted answer to this question says *I have personally messed 4 laptop hard disks simply because I failed to understand the right process.* I noticed that the same thing happened in several questions at Ask Ubuntu. I'm looking for more detailed information about whether it is safe to choose the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option in the Ubuntu installer.
3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? yes

Comment: I also found [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1009311) that meets the qualification of being asked by an active user with 1,000 points or less. This question is my number 2 candidate for the bounty question. I think that the last sentence of this question "is it safe to choose that option?" deserves additional attention.

Comment: Feel free to post that "another question" in a new meta answer; that might be a better suggestion.

Comment: @clearkimura 250 Bounty already open on that question.

Comment: @Fabby Oh, well... I just realized that "another question" was suggested in this same meta answer instead of a new one. I was too late to take notice.

Comment: [edited ... ago](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/18929/revisions)

Answer (score 4):

[Different colors for active/inactive Unity window title bars?](https://askubuntu.com/q/943147)

1. Bounty suggested: 250
2. Reason suggested: Ubuntu does not seem to be friendly enough to colour-blind users. The high contrast theme appears "broken" from my last testing in both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. So far nobody had suggested any alternative high contrast theme or easy method on how to change the active/inactive window title bars in Ubuntu--modifying the theme is tedious and not easy for most users.
3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? yes

Note: This was one of two questions I had put bounty (100) last month, but failed to get a good answer (as per comment in the linked post). If anyone knows how to solve and in mood to write an answer, then bounty may be given again here.

Comment: 250 bounty opened.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/q/828557/26246 in that case we went with decoration shadow as workaround.

Comment: @user.dz OP already know the workarounds as linked within the suggested question, and OP is looking for a real solution. Unfortunately, nobody seems to know the real one.

Answer (score 3):

[Is it possible to run Windows 10 UWP apps on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991858)

1. Bounty suggested: 250
2. Reason suggested: People tend to leave a potential answer as a comment; instead of comments, someone should write an answer why this is not possible. Previously I had left several comments to provide more clues, but that seems "still not easy" to answer. The question seems answerable already: Simply follow the clues and clarify each reference to come up with a reasonable answer. Except, this is tedious to do.
3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? yes

Note: This was another one of two questions I had put bounty (100) last month, which only received a plagiarized answer without any better references (as per comment in the linked post). If anyone is willing to clarify and sum up relevant information into a proper answer, then bounty may be given again here.

Answer (score 3):

[Can a Raspberry Pi run Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/212346)

1. Bounty suggested: 350
2. Reason suggested: This question was asked in late 2012, and the first (accepted) and second most voted answers are both outdated. There are several other answers that have been updated this year, but have less votes and thus underappreciated. The third most voted answer seems to be the best answer now.
3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? yes

Comment: I will provide bounty for this one (my turn, finally!) and I have opened the bounty with reason suggested.

Answer (score 2):

[How to format a SD card easily in KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/213511)

1. Bounty suggested: 250
2. Reason suggested: This question is most likely asked by users migrating to Ubuntu/Linux from Windows, which intends to find the equivalent feature of "right-click and format drive" that is found in Windows. Despite a seemingly simple question, nobody has found any two-clicks solution to have such feature in Ubuntu/Linux (KDE) since 2012 to this date.
3. Is asked by active user with points 1,000 or below? yes

Note: Such feature had been requested as per [this dated bug report (2009)](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209784), which was marked as "WONT FIX" or "RESOLVED INTENTIONAL". Even [the later discussion (2014)](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=112188&sid=13babb392cae25952fa43b5d2cbebc1d&start=15) on KDE community forum indicates that there was no easy solution.

**Precaution**: Judging by the difficulty of finding the solution, the bounty will likely be wasted unless someone--most experienced in scripting and KDE context menu--is willing to come up with a feasible solution.

Comment: Suggested to raise awareness, but bounty is *not recommended*.